# Is there way to see a list of possible arguments through IDE for Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio-3.0

When I code Flutter application in Android Studio I don't know what arguments certain object can take.Like in the code below: I would like to know what could I put in Scaffold after appBar as a second argument?

I tried to use Ctrl+P command - does nothing.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("appbar text")
        )

    //******WHAT COULD I PUT IN HERE ?******

    )
    );
  }
```

I expect there to be a list of objects I could pass as a parameters instead of constantly peeping into documentation/tutorials. Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this depending on what IDE you are using.

**VSCODE**

You can hover your mouse over the widget to see what items can go inside.

[image]

Or you can right click on `Scaffold` for example and click `Go to definition`.

[image]

This will give you a full list of inserts.

[image]

**Android Studio**

I don't know of being able to hover over Widgets in Android Studio as I don't use it but you can right click on the Widget and can select `Go To > Declaration`

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use **control ^ + Space** keys to show the list of possible arguments

[image: Keymap settings on Android Studio]

This is how it looks

[image: List of arguments]